# Doesn't Maven Dependency management create unnecessary dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have 3 projects, C1, C2, P. Where P is the parent project, C1 and C2 are child projects w.r.t. the pom.xml files. Let's say there are 2 dependencies D1 and D2. If C1 depends on D1 and C2 depends on D2, does it make sense to move both the dependencies on to the parent project? Won't adding to parent enforce C2 to depend on both D1 and D2 and not just D2? (similarly with C1)?

Comment: Add dependencies to a parent is in general not a good idea nor in your example which causes that the dependencies will be inherited from parent to childs which would result in C2 depending on D1 and D2 which was not intended. What you can do is to put the definitions (versions etc.) into parent (dependencyManagement) and just make the dependency into the child without version. So you have a central point where you can maintain the versions of the different dependencies.

Comment: What you will often see in this scenario is the parent has a properties called `d1.version` and `d2.version` which are then used as variables in the child modules when defining the dependencies.  This keeps the dependencies where they should be, but allows you to maintain dependency versions in one location.

Comment: @DMoses which does not help to prevent inherit the dependencies for both which you don't like to have. Apart from that such property things are hard to read and to maintain. Best is to have only a single location (dependencyManagement) for the versions you are using in your project.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't adding to parent enforce C2 to depend on both D1 and D2 and not just D2? (similarly with C1)?

Moving the D2 dependency from C2 to parent will make both C1 and C2 depend on D2.

In general, moving a dependency from a child to parent will make *all* children of the parent dependent on the moved dependency.

> Does it make sense to move both the dependencies on to the parent project?

This depends on what you try to achieve.

For example, if *every* module makes use of some utility library, then it may make sense to move the dependency to parent.

But if a dependency is only used by *one* of the child modules, then it doesn't make much sense to make *all* modules dependent on this dependency.

E.g. if a framework like Spring MVC is only used by the Web Application (controllers) module, then it doesn't make sense to make the Persistence layer module depend on Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice we should declare the dependencies or API's in parent projects which are used across all the child projects and which were version locked (version of the dependencies changes in extremely rare cases or not at all). So in your case.

does it make sense to move both the dependencies on to the parent project?

- If C1 depends on D1 and C2 depends on D2, its recommended to declare them in child projects.

Won't adding to parent enforce C2 to depend on both D1 and D2 and not just D2?

- Yes, It will.